# Playing Multiple Sound effects issue in cocos2d-x

Tags: c++, cocos2d-x, cocos2d-x-2.x

I have a sound effect 3sec long which need to be played repeatedly for some time of 10 to 15 secs. Implemented like below:

```
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect(powerUpSound, true);
```

But when I play an another sound effect, previous sound (`powerUpSound`) effect stops.

```
SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playEffect(starsSounds, false);
```

How can I play them both at the same time?

I'm using `Cocos2d-x v2.2.3`

Comment: If you dont use background music then you can play one of them with `SimpleAudioEngine::sharedEngine()->playBackgroundMusic();` Do you use Android device to run your app?

Comment: Yes, i am using android device and i have background music also in the game so can not play one of the effect as background music.

Comment: I've known that there is an issue with Android SoundPool class but it was about file size and duration but your files seem to be fine. Only workaround that comes to my mind is to make a new instance of SimpleAudioEngine and then play your sound

Answer (score 1):

I don't think it's a very good solution, but what I'm doing is going around the SimpleAudioEngine and using whatever it's hooking into to play sound:

```
#include "AudioEngine.h" 

std::string music_path = "gethit.mp3";
experimental::AudioEngine::play2d(music_path.c_str())
```

I think that this leaks memory or something, so you need to be careful when you use it. All I know is that it lets you play multiple sound effects at once on Android.

Comment: In fact, if someone were to tell me why this is a bad idea, I'd love to know.